# Infinite Scroll: Double Content in Chrome + Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

The code below works as intended in Firefox 19.0. The script loads random articles from a database.

It loads the same content repeatedly in Internet Explorer and loads double+different content in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{

$('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
$.ajax({
url: "loadmore.php",
success: function(html)
{
if(html)
{
$("#wrapper").append(html);
$('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
}else
{
$('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
}
}
});
}
});
</script>
```

here is loadmore.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 9");
if($stmt->execute()){
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo'
content here
';}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're always getting the same 9 elements because your MySQL query has no offset.

Try adding an offset, like this:

On loadmore.php

```
$limit=9;
$limit_offset = $limit*$_GET['offset'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':offset', $limit_offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

On your JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var offset = 0;
```

...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "loadmore.php",
    data: { offset: offset }
    success: function(html){
        if(html){
            offset++;
            $("#wrapper").append(html);
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
        } else {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just noticed it works in both Firefox and Chrome perfectly. This is an IE issue. I tried your fix but IE is still showing the same content. In fact, when I reload the page in IE, I SHOULD see different content, but I am seeing the same. Weird. Some sort of caching problem me thinks.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe if you post an example of your code in jsfiddle.net I can help you more...